# $(\mathbb{Q} , + )$ and $( \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} , +)$ are not isomorphic as groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

> Prove that $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$ and $(\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} , +)$ are not isomorphic as groups.

This question was asked in my abstract algebra quiz( now over) and I couldn't prove it.

I have been following Emil Artin.

I don't have any ideas on how this question should be approached.  I thought I should assume that a isomorphism $f$ exists in hope of getting some contradiction but I am unable to think of what exact proposition should I use and need some clues.

Comment: Maybe you can find some property that only one of those groups has? How about the property, for any two elements, there is a cyclic subgroup which contains both of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose they are, then there is a bijective homomorphism $f:\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}$. Let's say $$f\big((1,0)\big)=\frac{a_1}{b_1}\text{ and }f\big((0,1)\big)=\frac{a_2}{b_2}.$$
Then since $(a_2b_1)f((1,0))=(a_1b_2)f((0,1))=a_1a_2$, we have $f((a_2b_1,0))=f((0,a_1b_2))$ by applying the properties of homomorphisms.

This contradicts $f$ being a bijection.

Comment: $f((a_2b_1,0))=f((0,a_1b_2)) $  implies that $f(( a_2 ,b_1, -a_1 b_2))=(0,0)$ which implies atleast one of $a_2$ and $b_1$ is 0 and atleast one of  $a_1$ and $b_2 $ is 0. So, How is this a contradiction to definition of bijectio?

Comment: The $b_i$ can't be $0$ as that would make the images of $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ undefined. The $a_i$ also can't be $0$ as $f$ is an isomorphism by assumption, so the only element sent to $0$ is $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 5):

Well, I have one approach for "$(\mathbb{Q},+)$ is not isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}, +)$ as a group".

That is, "every finitely generated subgroup of $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ is cyclic " but for $(\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}, +)$ there exist some finitely generated subgroups which are not cyclic. For example, Subgroup generated by $S={(1,0),(0,1)}$  is finitely generated but the subgroup generated by the set $S$ is $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ which is not cyclic.

Comment: Use `$\times$` for $\times$. The symbol $*$ means something very specific in group theory.

Comment: @Shaun yes, thank you I just edited my text.